# Set Knockout dropdown value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a dropdown value which is proving very difficult to set in the console. I have tried using Jquery .val and using document.getEWlementById.value and both will not set the item. Does anyone know how I can set the value of the dropdown using the value? I think the problem is that it is using Knockout which makes it more difficult to set it dynamically.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="sourceShippingLocations" data-bind="options: $root.ShippingLocations, optionsText:'Name', optionsCaption:'Select location', value: $root.SelectedOriginShippingLocation" class="form-control" title="">
    <option value="">Select location</option>
    <option value="">doo Warehouse</option>
    <option value="">moo</option>
    <option value="">Manchester</option>
</select>
```

Comment: All the `<option>` tags are rendered by Knockout.  Its source is `$root.ShippingLocations`.  More information:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html.

Comment: Are you looking for [optionsValue](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) ?

Comment: Is this the html rendered by knockout? Because all your values in the html look empty.

Comment: you missed optionsValue,  you can set the dropdown then with `$root. SelectedOriginShippingLocation(value)`

Answer (score 4):

Knockout doesn't make it "more difficult to set dynamically". It just works differently.

In knockout, a viewmodel dictates what happens in the view. In other words: you don't set the value of the select through modifying the attribute directly, but you change the selected value of the underlying *model* and knockout manages the UI state for you.

Each of the `<option>` elements represents a value in an array named `$root.ShippingLocations`. The selected value is stored in `$root.SelectedOriginShippingLocation`.

In the viewmodel, you'd update the current selection by doing something like:

```
 this.SelectedOriginShippingLocation(this.ShippingLocations()[0])
```

(this sets the selection to the first shipping location)

If you want to see this in action without having to modify the viewmodel, you can hack this in your console:

```
var root = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("sourceShippingLocations")).$root;
root.SelectedOriginShippingLocation(ko.unwrap(root.ShippingLocations)[0]);

// change 0 for the index you like
```